# Generics method usage

Tags: java, c#, selenium, generics, selenium-webdriver

I have this code in C#:

```
private static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
{
    var page = new T();
    PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, page);
    return page;
}
public static AboutPage About
{
   get { return GetPage<AboutPage>(); }
}
```

I was trying to implement this in Java, as I really liked the concept, but I'm not good with generics (and especially with c#). So, that's my code:

```
private static <T> T getPage(Class<? extends T> cls) throws Exception{
    T page = cls.newInstance();
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, page);
    return page;
}
public static LoginPage Login() {
    return LoginPage.getPage();
}
```

It's not working at all. I feel like I'm missing fundamentals, so I'd really appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: _It's not working at all_ is not a useful remark. Please explain _what_ is not working.

Comment: @JornVernee In the following code, I get: "Cannot resolve method getPage()" for example. TBH, I'm not even sure, that I implemented it even close to logically proper solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. But you don't show the implementation of ```LoginPage.getPage()```. Who's signature is not compatible with the above method.

Comment: @JornVernee But I thought above generics method getPage() the one I'm trying to call. I'm just not sure what to pass as an argument.

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks a lot, that seems to work.

Comment: @JornVernee Sorry for asking you here, but if you know, what is java`s alternative to:  public static string Title {  get  { return webDriver.Title; }   } Cause it's really interesting, like 'Title' here is field, not a method. At least it seems to me like that.

Comment: You can't do that in Java. You'll have to create a `getTitle` accessor method. That's the beauty of C# :)

Comment: @EvilTak Oh, ok, I get it. Thx for the clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private static <T> T getPage(Supplier<? extends T> supp) {
    T page = supp.get();
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, page);
    return page;
}

public static LoginPage Login() {
    return getPage(LoginPage::new); // Passing the default constructor
}
```

Here I switch out the instantiation of `T` from `Class`, to instantiation from a `Supplier`, since it does not throw exceptions.

---

If you don't have Java 8, you would have to use your code, and call like:

```
getPage(LoginPage.class);
```

But that would also mean having to deal with the exceptions.