# cannot instantiate the type T Error

Tags: java, c#

```
private static <T> T GetPage()  
{
    T page = new T();
    PageFactory.initElements(BrowserFactory.getWebDriver(), page);
    return page;
}
```

T page = new T() ---- says Error: cannot instantiate the type T

I am completely new to this. Can you help me why I am getting this error?
Below is my C# code for the same thing and it works fine. Am not able to replicate this in Java.

```
private static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
{
   var page = new T();
   PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, page);
   return page;
}
```

Comment: Why tag Java? Generics aren't really the same in the 2 languages...

Comment: Rather, why tag it c#, considering this question is about an issue with java-code.

Comment: @J.Steen That is not java...

Comment: @NemanjaT The top bit. The one that has an issue. Not the bottom bit.

Comment: @J.Steen Sorry, overlooked

Comment: I've answered this one before: [Generics method usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311064/generics-method-usage/38311339), though I'd say the title doesn't really make it a good duplicate.

Comment: Check this answer, it should give you a clue about how to instantiate generic types in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1090488/3731444